# Custom meta fields not showing up in WP_Response Object via custom endpoint

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, loop, post-meta

I created my own Custom Post Type called `person` and a corresponding end route. I can modify my posts with the endpoint, using functions as `wp_update_post`,`wp_insert_post` and `get_posts`. I am facing a problem now, where I want to return the object information with Postman.

Using `get_posts` on the custom endpoint only returns default fields as post_title, and so on. But if I use the wordpress endpoints as `/wp-json/wp/v2/person` I am able to view all entries with the custom fields. How can I view them on my own URL instead?

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init' , 'custom_meta_fields' ); 

function custom_meta_fields(){
register_rest_field('person', 'first_name',array(
    'get_callback' => 'get_first_name',
));
}


function get_first_name( $object ){

    $id = $object['id'];
    return get_post_meta( $id , 'first_name' );
}
```

Endpoints:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
$version = '1';
$namespace = 'custom/v'. $version;
$base = 'person';

register_rest_route( $namespace, '/author/', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'getposts',
) );

register_rest_route( $namespace, '/'. $base . '/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'getperson',
    ),

    array(
        'methods' => 'PUT',
        'callback' => 'putperson',
    ),

    array(
        'methods' => 'DELETE',
        'callback' => 'deleteperson',
    ),
) );

register_rest_route( $namespace, '/'. $base, array(
    array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'getpersons',
    ),

    array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'postcustomperson',
    ),
) );});
```

Code for `getpersons` :

```
function getpersons() {
$persons = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'person',
) );

return $persons;
```

Comment: What's the code for your endpoint? That seems more relevant to your question than this code.

Comment: I have edited the post. Thank you for your help.